# Is MongoDB classified as a DBSM or just a DB?

Tags: database, non-relational-database

A DBSM allows the user to create and manipulate a database. Isnt that exactly what MongoDB allows us to do? I am a little confused because I never see anyone refer to MongoDB as a non-relational DBSM.

Isnt it in effect a DBSM and a DB in one package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB is the database. The fact that it ships with a web UI that you can use to create and manipulate contents does, I suppose, make it a DBSM as well - albeit one that only works for Mongo, in comparison to something like DbVisualizer which works with multiple databases.